# Number of positive integer solutions of diophantine inequality.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, linear-diophantine-equations

Given a Diophantine inequality of the form $$a_{1}x_{1}+a_{2}x_{2}+\dots+a_{n}x_{n}\leq N $$ How many positive integer solutions does it have? Here all $a_{i}\geq0$ and $x_{i}\geq 0$.

I was able to find some solutions by considering special cases. Supposing all $x_{i}=0, i\neq 1$. We get,
$$a_{1}x_{1}\leq N$$
$$x_{1}\leq\frac{N}{a_{1}}$$
And similarly for other terms we can find that the given Diophantine inequality has at least $$\lfloor\frac{N}{a_{1}}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{N}{a_{2}}\rfloor+\dots+\lfloor\frac{N}{a_{n}}\rfloor$$ positive integer solutions. I am stuck here and has no idea how to procced forward. I am looking for general method or way to find number of positive solution of any Diophantine inequality. Thank You!

Comment: Are your $a_i$'s supposed to be non-negative integers? And what about the $x_i$'s?

Comment: If one of the $a_i$'s is $0,$ there are infinitly many solutions. E.g. if $a_1=0$, every $(x_1,0,0,\dots,0)$ is a solution.

Comment: Yes, all $a_{i}$ are positive integers. I am sorry. I should have mentioned it in my original question.

Comment: Do you really mean positive ($>0$), or rather non-negative ($\ge0$)?

Comment: So, I have made some edit in my question. So, $a_{i}$'s are $\geq 0$ and I am trying to find $x_{i}$'s that are also  $\geq 0$.